# Min and Max, but there are also letters

Tags: mysql

I'll keep this as simple as I can, I'm new to MySQL and I have values in my column such as "10, 5, 3 and n/v", the code is

```
SELECT MIN(InsertColumnHere), MAX(InsertColumnHere)
FROM diplomaeval
```

and the result is..

> MIN = 10 and MAX = N/V

I need for them to be "switched" places so they go to their respective places, as N/V is the lowest and 10 is the highest, not the other way around.

Comment: A warning the column probably is VARCHAR, alphabetical, so 10 < 2 < 22 < 3 < N/V.

Comment: If you moved to having a nullable `INT` type column, then `N/V` could simply be `NULL`, which just so happens to be sorted as "less than" any non-null value.